# Android Simple Unit Test Succeeds when Clearly Wrong

Tags: android, junit

Whenever I run a simple JUnit test on Android studio, the tests always succeed no matter what..

I already hit Build Variant and this is under Unit Tests.

```
public class ECUserTests extends InstrumentationTestCase{

    public void test() throws Exception{
        final int expected = 1;
        final int reality = 5;
        assertEquals(expected, reality);
    }
```

I added

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
```

To my build.gradle file and now this is something that clearly isn't true is returning as passed.

Comment: Where did you import `assertEquals` from?

Answer (score 0):

For the new unit test support, you don't need to inherit from `InstrumentationTestCase`, but you do need to annotate your test method.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ECUserTests {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    final int expected = 1;
    final int reality = 5;
    assertEquals(expected, reality);
  }

}
```

Comment: I actually did annotate just wasn't copy pasted in :( Will edit now.

Answer (score -1):

To run unit test, it's required to select "Unit test" in Test Artifact under Build Variants and Android Studio version must be >1.1

[image]